# iteration with ng-repeat on nested JSON

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How do I use ng-repeat if my JSON looks like

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "shop_name": "Shop Name",
        "user_id": "2",
        "shop_email": "",
        "shop_address": "",
        "shop_phone": "",
        "company_name": "",
        "description": "",
        "shop_provision": null,
        "created_at": "2014-11-05 10:32:32",
        "updated_at": "2014-11-06 21:02:00",
        "banners": [
            {
                "id": "18",
                "disk_name": "545be1dfa2011452107756.png",
                "file_name": "Screenshot from 2014-11-06 09:50:48.png",
                "file_size": "135441",
                "content_type": "image/png",
                "title": null,
                "description": null,
                "field": "banners",
                "sort_order": "18",
                "created_at": "2014-11-06 21:02:23",
                "updated_at": "2014-11-06 21:02:34",
                "path": "/uploads/public/545/be1/dfa/545be1dfa2011452107756.png",
                "extension": "png"
            },
            {
                "id": "20",
                "disk_name": "545be1e6b5048131391528.png",
                "file_name": "Screenshot from 2014-11-06 09:50:48.png",
                "file_size": "135441",
                "content_type": "image/png",
                "title": null,
                "description": null,
                "field": "banners",
                "sort_order": "20",
                "created_at": "2014-11-06 21:02:30",
                "updated_at": "2014-11-06 21:02:34",
                "path": "/uploads/public/545/be1/e6b/545be1e6b5048131391528.png",
                "extension": "png"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

on banners I would like iterate again

On controller I get a JSON object or array which contains a subObject (responseJSON)

```
october.controllers['dashboard/wm'] = function ($scope, $request) {

     $scope.banners = $request('onGetBanners'); //the $request is an ajax function
     console.log($scope.banners);  
}
```

the subObject

responseJSON looks like as the result in firebug console

```
Object { result="[{"id":"1","shop_name":"...","extension":"png"}]}]"}
```

from all this I want the result=

than I try to iterate the scope like

```
<div ng-repeat="banner in banners.responseJSON.result track by $index"></div>
```

**Update**

I changed the way as I initiate the scope in controller

```
october.controllers['publishers/wm'] = function ($scope, $request) {

    $request('onGetBanners', {success: function(data){
        this.success(data).done(function() {
              $scope.response = data.result;
            });
    }})     

}
```

than again trying iterate

```
{% verbatim %}

{{response}} //outputs 
[
    {
        "id": "2",
        "shop_name": "Test Shop",
        "user_id": "1",
        "shop_email": null,
        "shop_address": null,
        "shop_phone": null,
        "company_name": null,
        "description": "",
        "shop_provision": null,
        "created_at": "2014-11-05 11:31:15",
        "updated_at": "2014-11-05 11:31:15",
        "banners": []
    }
]

<div ng-repeat="shop in response track by $index">
     {{ shop.shop_name }} //no data
</div>
{% endverbatim %}
```

if I remove `track by $index` I get

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: shop in response, Duplicate key: string:", Duplicate value: "\""
```

**Got it and I never gonna forget this pain**

```
angular.fromJson(jsondata)
```

Comment: so you have a controller that sets `$scope.responseJSON = json;`? Can you show us the controller?

Comment: yes the scope looks like that

Comment: sorry I have to correct myself I will update the post

Comment: is `$request` async or not? also the banners variable seems to store shops not banners, variable naming is important for readability

Comment: yes $request is async. Is an ajax function which retrieves remote data on iterate I will change the variable name. I was tying from controller to initiate scope with the result directly but somehow won't work

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like this?

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="shop in responseJson">
    {{shop.id}}
    <div ng-repeat="banner in shop.banners">
        <img ng-src="{{banner.path}}>
    </div>
</div>
```

See on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michiganfootball20/41h0a7xh/)